# How to get errors from a system freeze? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an HP laptop (4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, Intel Pentium n3700) and I am having a constant freezing problem.

Nothing appears to work, Ctrl + Alt + F1, Alt + R + E + I + S + U + B.

In a [community page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze), I've found a way to get the errors of the freezing via SSH. But it looks like it gets completely stuck, even the networking (wifi & ethernet)

When I hard reset my laptop and start Ubuntu again, I don't get any error message, as usually appears. What can I do for getting an exact diagnosis and fixing those freezes?

Comment: I am just curious, but why would one install 14.04 when 17.10 (or 18.04) exists? (I am using 17.10 on single core, 1GB RAM notebook)

Comment: I use some simulation packages that explicitly work only on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out. Maybe my kernel was not working properly with the drivers I had to use. I tried installing another kernel version. (Works most of the time).

An amazing program for doing that is [Ukuu](https://fossbytes.com/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu-mint-ukuu/).

First add the repositories:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

Now update them:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the program:

```
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

And then launch it from the launchpad or via the terminal by:

```
sudo ukuu-gtk
```

[image]

Inside the program, you can choose the kernel you want. Then, it downloads and installs it.
As the program indicates, those are the common errors that you have, caused by a non compatible kernel.

Hope it helps...